# Kluft oder Diskrepanz

Tags: difference, word-choice, synonym

> **Kluft:** ein tiefer Gegensatz zwischen zwei Personen, ihren Meinungen und Haltungen / scharfer Gegensatz
>
> **Diskrepanz:** Widersprüchlichkeit, Missverhältnis zwischen zwei Dingen oder Personen /  ein deutlicher Unterschied zwischen zwei Dingen

Quelle: TheFreeDictionary.com, Duden

Worin liegt der Unterschied zwischen den zwei Wörtern?

Comment: Nebeninformation: Nur die Kluft kann für eine Spalte (z. B. ein Grabenbruch) verwendet werden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eine **Kluft** ist viel stärker und tiefer, schwerer zu überwinden. Eine **Diskrepanz** ist kleiner. Man sagt zum Beispiel „kleinere Diskrepanzen“ aber nicht „kleinere Klüfte“.

Eine Diskrepanz zwischen Dingen bedeutet, dass sie nicht gleich sind, dass etwas fehlt, oder anders sein sollte.

> Es gibt noch Diskrepanzen zwischen der Leistung von und den Erwartungen an Herrn Müller.

Das impliziert aber auch, dass diese Diskrepanzen überwunden werden können.

> Nach der Scheidung gab es eine Kluft zwischen den ehemaligen Partnern.

bedeutet, dass die Kluft wohl so schnell nicht überwunden wird.

Comment: Während eine Kluft zwingend groß ist, ist eine Diskrepanz nicht zwingend klein. Zum Beispiel: »Es gibt große Diskrepanzen Leistung von und den Erwartungen an Herrn Müller.« Diskrepanz ist einfach ein neutraler Begriff, der nichts über die Größe der Gegensätze aussagt.